# XSL for-each. incorrect output in tr tag

Tags: xslt, foreach, html-table, divider

There is my problem:
I have to do table with products in my site with xslt.
Here is how should it looks:

[image: How should it looks]

Now it looks like this:

[image: Looks now]

So, my question is how to do these dividing lines between `<tr>` tags?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <table id="producers_table"  >

      <xsl:for-each select="document('udata://catalog/getCategoryList/void/producers//1/')/udata/items/item[not(@country=preceding-sibling::item/@country)]" >

       <xsl:variable name="country_name" select="@country" />
       <xsl:variable name="country_count" select="count($country_name)"/>

       <tr id="test">

       <td id="country_td">
      <xsl:value-of select="document(concat('uobject://', $country_name))/udata/object/@name"/>

       </td>     

        <xsl:for-each select="../item[@country = $country_name]">

  <xsl:variable name="prod_count" select="document(concat('udata://catalog/getCountObjects/', @id))/udata"/>

                            <td umi:element-id="{@id}">

                                            <a href="{@link}" umi:field-name="name" umi:delete="delete" umi:empty="&empty-section-name;">
                <table class="object_table">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">     
<img src="{document(concat('upage://', @id, '.header_pic'))//value}"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" id="search_by_appointment_name">
        <p>
    <span><xsl:variable name="curr_producer_name" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$curr_producer_name" />
</span>


&#160;<sup class="object_count"><xsl:value-of select="$prod_count"/></sup>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </a>
     </td>  
         </xsl:for-each>   
</tr>

</xsl:for-each>

</table>
```

Where should I add `<hr/>`?

P.S. Here is some results of my attempts:

1.

[image: Attempt 1]

code:

```
<table id="producers_table"  >

  <xsl:for-each select="document('udata://catalog/getCategoryList/void/producers//1/')/udata/items/item[not(@country=preceding-sibling::item/@country)]" >

   <xsl:variable name="country_name" select="@country" />
   <xsl:variable name="country_count" select="count($country_name)"/>

   <tr id="test">
      **<hr/>**
```

2.

[image: Attempt 2]

```
&#160;<sup class="object_count"><xsl:value-of select="$prod_count"/></sup>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </a>
     </td>  
         </xsl:for-each>   
         **<hr/>**
</tr>

</xsl:for-each>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, it's not legal to put an `<hr />` directly inside a `<tr>`.  You could try putting this right before the second `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="10">
    <hr />
  </td>
</tr>
```

But in this day and age, you shouldn't be using tables for layout. I think the correct solution here would be to rework your HTML so it uses `<div>`s instead of tables. Then it should be easy to put the `<hr/>`s where you want them.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a css class in a style tag for your `td` that has `border-bottom: 1px solid gray`. That should get the effect your going for.